# Вернуть записи, значение одного из полей у которых неизменно

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида id, email, ip
значения столбцов email и ip не уникальны

пример:

```
1 email1@example.com 123.456.0.1
2 email1@example.com 123.456.0.2
3 email1@example.com 123.456.0.3
4 email2@example.com 123.456.0.1
5 email2@example.com 123.456.0.1
6 email2@example.com 123.456.0.1
```

Требуется выбрать записи, у которых неизменно значение ip (то есть, для примера выше это окажутся записи **только** с email = **email2@example.com**, потому что значения ip одинаковые)

Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать такую выборку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таблицу назвать alpha, а поля - email и ip, то вот код:

```
SELECT email FROM alpha
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip) = 1
```

На выходе:

```
Query result:
+--------------------+
| email              |
+--------------------+
| email2@example.com |
+--------------------+
Affected rows: 1
```

Полный код для проверки:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha(
    alpha_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    ip VARCHAR(30)    
);
INSERT alpha (email,ip) VALUES 
("email1@example.com", '123.456.0.1'),
("email1@example.com", "123.456.0.2"),
("email1@example.com", "123.456.0.3"),
("email2@example.com", "123.456.0.1"),
("email2@example.com", "123.456.0.1"),
("email2@example.com", "123.456.0.1");
SELECT email FROM alpha
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip) = 1
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: большое спасибо! а то я со временными таблицами возился